# How to delay hiding on this script with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I use simple jquery to hide and unhide two menus when click on link in third:

```
<script>
    $('#iii').on('click', function(){
    $('#menuk').addClass('hiden'),$('#menuitt').removeClass('hiden');
});
$('#kkk').on('click', function(){
    $('#menuitt').addClass('hiden'),$('#menuk').removeClass('hiden');
});
    </script>
```

It works like it should, but how insert easing animation with delay into hide and appear events?

Comment: Do you mean you want to fadeIn and fadeOut?

Comment: Yes, fadein/out with delay would be wonderfull

Comment: Ok, so use `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`

Comment: .fadein(2000) works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) like this

```
<script>
    $('#iii').on('click', function(){
    $('#menuk').addClass('hiden'),$('#menuitt').delay(500).removeClass('hiden');
});
$('#kkk').on('click', function(){
    $('#menuitt').addClass('hiden'),$('#menuk').delay(500).removeClass('hiden');
});
    </script>
```

`delay(500)` means delay 500 milliseconds